# Firebase remote Config server value are same as default?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

We are using remote config in our application, and since yesterday our remote value are not reflecting on apps it was working before. Due to this some of over feature breaks and produce crash.

```
FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig;
        FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings;

        mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
        configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .build();

        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(configSettings);
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(R.xml.firebase_remote_config_defaults);

        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(getCacheExpiration(mFirebaseRemoteConfig))
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        // If is successful, activated fetched
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            MyloLogger.e("FIREBASE_REMOTE_CONFIG", "CONFIG_FETCHED");
                            mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                            setFirebaseConfigData(mFirebaseRemoteConfig, false);
                        } else {
                            MyloLogger.e("FIREBASE_REMOTE_CONFIG", "ERROR - KILLLLLL MMMMEEEE ");
                        }
                    }
                });
        setFirebaseConfigData(mFirebaseRemoteConfig, true);`

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.3'
```

This code was working previously, and suddenly not responding.

Comment: I really doubt that anyone could solve this without any details

Comment: I just shared the code, I have posted the same on Firebase support but that take sometime. This seems to be firebase sdk issue but not able to conclude the same.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved, the problem with the A/B testing regex which is fail and not showing any error. I think Firebase should have some kind of process the errors over there.